# NZSQL/CODE - USE [DATABASE NAME] at start of Query

Tags: sql, netezza

Everyone.

We use a lot of queries that are saved on a network drive instead of used as stored procedures and then they are opened and ran as needed.

When using TSQL we would often specify a

> USE [DATABASE NAME]

to direct the query to correct database. But now as we are switching to NZSQL I was wondering if there is an equivalent. I know you could possibly work around it by listing the DB name before each table like:

> DATABASE1..TABLE1

But I was wondering if there is a similar function as to that in TSQL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version you are using, you can use "SET CATALOG DBNAME;" to specify the database connection.  You can verify this by issuing SELECT CURRENT_CATALOG.

I don't recall exactly which version introduced this, but it's there at least as of 7.0.3.

If you are using the NZSQL CLI (rather than just using NZSQL to refer the Netezza dialect of SQL, then you can specify a database connection using "\c DBNAME".

Comment: "SET CATALOG DBNAME;" worked for me! Thank you! You are awesome Scott!

Comment: Also, for anyone who might come across this with the same question. We are using a Netezza client (Aginity). We are finding that the program has a lot of potential and perks over TSQL, but the limited resources for Netezza and the lack of help on Aginity forums, make it hard to get started. Thanks agian, Scott!